# Accuracy value goes up and down on the training process

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, image-classification

After training the network I noticed that accuracy goes up and down. Initially I thought it is caused by the learning rate, but it is set to quite small value. Please check the screenshot attached.
[Plot Accuracy Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wJ7b.png)

My network (in Pytorch) looks as follow:

```
class Network(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Network,self).__init__()
    
    self.layer1 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(3,16,kernel_size=3),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(2)
    )
    
    self.layer2 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(16,32, kernel_size=3),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(2)
        )
    
    self.layer3 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(32,64, kernel_size=3),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(2)
    )       
  
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(17*17*64,512)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512,1)
    self.relu = nn.ReLU()
    self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()
    
    
def forward(self,x):
    out = self.layer1(x)
    out = self.layer2(out)
    out = self.layer3(out)
    out = out.view(out.size(0),-1)
    out = self.relu(self.fc1(out))
    out = self.fc2(out)
    out = torch.sigmoid(out)
    return out
```

I am using **RMSprop** as optimizer and **BCELoss** as criterion. The **learning rate** is set to 0.001

Here is the training process:

```
epochs = 15
itr = 1
p_itr = 100
model.train()
total_loss = 0
loss_list = []
acc_list = []
for epoch in range(epochs):
    for samples, labels in train_loader:
        samples, labels = samples.to(device), labels.to(device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model(samples)
        labels = labels.unsqueeze(-1)
        labels = labels.float()
        loss = criterion(output, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        total_loss += loss.item()
        scheduler.step()
    
    if itr%p_itr == 0:
        pred = torch.argmax(output, dim=1)
        correct = pred.eq(labels)
        acc = torch.mean(correct.float())
        print('[Epoch {}/{}] Iteration {} -> Train Loss: {:.4f}, Accuracy: {:.3f}'.format(epoch+1, epochs, itr, total_loss/p_itr, acc))
        loss_list.append(total_loss/p_itr)
        acc_list.append(acc)
        total_loss = 0
        
    itr += 1
```

My dataset is quite small - 2000 train and 1000 validation (binary classification 0/1). I wanted to do the 80/20 split but I was asked to keep it like that. I was thinking that the architecture might be too complex for such a small dataset.

Any hits what may cause such jumps in the training process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code here is wrong: `pred = torch.argmax(output, dim=1)`

This line using for multiclass classification with Cross-Entropy Loss.
Your task is binary classification so the `pred` values are wrong. Change to:

```
if itr%p_itr == 0:
  pred = torch.round(output)
  ....
```

You can change your optimizer to `Adam`, `SGD`, or `RMSprop` to find the suitable optimizer that helps your model coverage faster.
Also change the `forward()` function:

```
def forward(self,x):
   out = self.layer1(x)
   out = self.layer2(out)
   out = self.layer3(out)
   out = out.view(out.size(0),-1)
   out = self.relu(self.fc1(out))
   out = self.fc2(out)
   return self.sigmoid(out) #use your forward is ok, but this cleaner
```